# Register multiple EF contexts into a DI container

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject, repository-pattern

I'm starting to develop an application  using Domain Driven Design concepts and applying n-layer patterns for the architecture. My problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082488/best-practice-of-repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern-with-multiple-dbcontext): because I need to create one or more database contexts.

Instead of to instantiate my contexts using the `new` keyword, I'm using Ninject to create a D.I. container and resolve all dependencies automatically, but here starts the confusion!

This is basically what I have here:

```
public interface IDataContext : IDisposable 
{ 
}

public abstract class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext 
{
}

public class ContextA : DataContext
{
}

public class ContextB : DataContext
{
}
```

The first question is how to register the contexts, when they are implementing the same interface?

And the second question is how should to call the repositories, e.g.:

```cs
public class MyClass(IUserRepository userRepository, IBankRepository bankRepository)
{
  // IUserRepository is inside ContextA
  // IBankRepository is inside ContextB
}
```

In the sample code above, I'd like to use the same UnitOfWork. Is that possible?

Comment: If you use a UnitOfWork pattern, then you'll only have 1 datacontext and then there's no reason to bother with registering in an IOC container

Comment: Anyway DbContext already implements IDisposable.

Comment: How are you going to use ContextA and ContextB? Why do you have 2 of them? Are you using 2 different databases?

Comment: I'll have a lot of entities, so I need to break contexts, and in some situations I'll need to access other databases! The second reason is described at related question.

Comment: I use multiple DbContexts which I inject using Ninject but they all use the same model (different database engine / provider). One problem I ran into was EF couldn't handle using two different DbContexts at the same time. The only way I found around it was loading the contexts in different AppDomains. So a single UnitOfWork I think may be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have users in ContextA and banks in ContextB you should reflect it in your interfaces so the repository is constructed with the context containing the expected entities :

```
public interface IDataContext : IDisposable 
{ 
}

public interface IContextA : IDataContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 
}

public interface IContextB : IDataContext
{
   public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; } 
}

public abstract class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext 
{
}

public class ContextA : DataContext, IContextA
{
}

public class ContextB : DataContext, IContextB
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The first question is how to register the contexts, when they are
>   implementing the same interface?

This is where your problem is. According to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) implementations of an abstraction should be interchangable without causing the consumer to break. Since each DbContext will have its own model, a consumer will typically expect one particular data model and will break (at runtime) when you supply it with a different model.

And this violation directly causes you trouble with registration. So the solution is to give each context its own abstraction and register those abstractions separately.

Comment: What if you want to run multiple implementations of the same interface next to each other? For instance I have QuickSortAlgoritm and CoutingSortAlgoritm and both implement ISortAlgoritm and I have a class with methods QuickSort(int[] numbers) and CoutingSort(int[] numbers). How to use DI to inject both instances?

Comment: @MartiendeJong: seems great for its own StackOverflow question full with code examples.

Comment: From what I read his implementations could very well be interchangable so I added a different example in which it is clear that they are interchangable.