# ASP.Net MVC: working with multiple repositories & injection by Unity DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am working with asp.net mvc 5 project. suppose i am showing Customer data where i am showing customer detail and customer favorite products.

so i fetch data from customer repository, country repository and favorite repository.

many time people write article on injection repository by unity DI. when i am working with single repository then this concept make sense but when i have to fetch data from multiple repositories then how could i inject multiple repositories in mvc controller ctor by unity di?

see a small code for injecting repository by unity DI.

```
public class FooController : Controller  
{  
     readonly IFooRepository _repository;  

     // Inject here  
     public ProductController(IFooRepository repository)  
     {  
           _repository = repository;   
     }  

     // Use it here  
     public ActionResult Bar()  
     {  
          var bar = _repository.DoSomething();  
     }  
}
```

above code refer from https://forums.asp.net/t/2105895.aspx?Repository+inject+into+controller+by+Unity+DI

now tell me how could i refactor my code or what approach i should follow as a result i can work with multiple repositories and also can inject by Unity DI.

please give me best guidance. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add any dependency you require into the controller's constructor.

```
public class FooController : Controller  
{  
    readonly IFooRepository _repository;  
    readonly IOtherRepository _otherRepository;  

    public ProductController(IFooRepository repository, IOtherRepository otherRepository)  
    {  
        _repository = repository;   
        _otherRepository = otherRepository;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that while *L-Four*'s [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808949/265165) is a often a good way to go, you might run into difficulties later when you did some modification to loaded entities and want to save them, as you probably ended up having separate `DBContext` instances inside of your repositories. But it depends on your Repository and DI implementation and configuration...

Example:

```
// Assume you want to create a new User with associated Account

var user = _usersRepository.AddUser(new User(....));
var account = _accountRepository.AddAccount(new Account{ ... User = user });

// Now you want to save them both in one transaction... how?
_usersRepository.Commit();
_accountRepository.Commit(); // What if this fails? you have an orphaned user?
```

To solve this problem, I'd recommend implementing the so called **Unit Of Work** pattern. There are some [good examples](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/a-better-entity-framework-unit-of-work-pattern-DD) also on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26082488/265165) and [elsewhere](https://dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-aspnet-core/).

Might save you some headache for later.

Your updated code will be:

```
public class FooController : Controller  
{  
     readonly IUsersAndAccountUnitOfWork _uow;  

     // Inject here  
     public ProductController(IUsersAndAccountUnitOfWork uow)  
     {  
           _uow = uow;
     }  

     // Use it here  
     public ActionResult Bar()  
     {  
           var user = _uow.Users.AddUser(new User(....));
           var account = _uow.Accounts.AddAccount(new Account{ ... User = user });

           _uow.Commit();
     }  
}
```

Comment: You could simply register the db context in such a way that only one instance exists and that it only lives in the scope of the specific (web) request.

Comment: @L-Four Yes! but it's good to have a single `Commit` method. If it's on Repository level, I'd expect it to actually apply to that Repository only, e.g. `userRepository.Commit()` should commit my changes to Users only, I don't want it to also Commit changes in `myOtherRepository`.

Comment: @thmshd would you please post a small complete sample code just to show the flow of your code? did you use any DI to map between IRepository and Repository for automatic passing to controller?

Comment: I would not expose commits in repositories. The context is created and destroyed independent of repositories, and passed to the repositories as a dependency for example.

Comment: @L-Four I wouldn't expose commits in repositories either, I don't understand how your attempt is to commit multiple changes done across multiple repositories, at once. Where does your `Commit` method sit, who is responsible to execute `Commit` on the DbContext? Surely, you don't want every single `AddXYZ(...)` method to commit, and you need to control that because you might need the new Entity IDs for further processing. This is where the _Unit Of Work_ pattern comes into play.

Comment: @Mist Follow this Microsoft tutorial: [__Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application__](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to learn about the patterns... Repository and Unit Of Work often go hand-in-hand